# tbb layer dimension mismatch CNN/Pytorch code

Tags: c++, debugging, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tbb

I have a CNN testing code that is reading CNN parameters from pytorch training data and test it on CNN the code was working fine but I tried to use tbb parallel_for with it to improve performance so I change the loop from

```
for (j = 0; j < layerstrings.size(); j++) {
    LAYER_INF *p = layerstrings.at(j);
    arg1 = p->arg1;
    arg2 = p->arg2;
    arg3 = p->arg3;
    arg4 = p->arg4;
    arg5 = p->arg5;
```

to

```
parallel_for(size_t(0), layerstrings.size(), [&](size_t j) {
    LAYER_INF *p = layerstrings.at(j);
    arg1 = p->arg1;
    arg2 = p->arg2;
    arg3 = p->arg3;
    arg4 = p->arg4;
    arg5 = p->arg5;
```

but I keep getting this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tbb::captured_exception'
```

what():  layer dimension mismatch!
output size of Nth layer must be equal to input of (N+1)th layer
layerN:           conv in:784([[28x28x1],[5x5x6],[1x1x6]]), out:3456([[24x24x6]])
layerN+1: fully-connected in:160([[160x1x1],[160x10x1],[10x1x1]]), out:10([[10x1x1]])
3456 != 160

The PyTorch cnn structure looks like

```
model = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Conv2d(1,6,5),
      nn.AvgPool2d(2,2),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Conv2d(6,10,5),
      nn.AvgPool2d(2,2),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Flatten(),
      nn.Linear(160,10),
      nn.Sigmoid()
    )
```

any idea or suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is mostly arising because of the lack of space to run your CNN. Can you just check if you have enough RAm to run your CNN model with the specified dimension? You can also refer to the below link for further clarification

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/tbb-documentation/top/intel-threading-building-blocks-developer-reference/appendices/deprecated-features/obsolete-c-functionality/exceptions/capturedexception.html